# SQL server: delete rows and all rows in according tables, according to foreign key contraints

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-delete

When I try to delete an entry in a table in my SQL-Server DB, I get following error message:

```
---------------------------
Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
---------------------------
No rows were deleted.

A problem occurred attempting to delete row 1.
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Error Message: 
  The DELETE statement conflicted with 
  the REFERENCE constraint "ref_Other_Table".
  The conflict occurred in database "DB_Name",
  table "namespace.Other_Table_Name", column 'RefId'.

The statement has been terminated.

Correct the errors and attempt to delete the row again or 
press ESC to cancel the change(s).
---------------------------
OK   Help   
---------------------------
```

I am aware that this issue is caused by a foreign key constraint, and the general idea is to do the corresponding deletion in `Other_Table`, but the problem is that, when doing that, I get a similar error message concerning `Again_Other_Table`, and it goes on and on until I reach the end of the "foreign key tree".

I believe this could be done in a much easier way:

- Configure all foreign key constraints to be `Cascade` (instead of ±`Blocking`, as it seems to be done currently).
- Remove the tuple in the first table. The foreign key constraints (being `Cascade` now), will remove all corresponding tuples in `Other_Table`, `Another_Table` and all `Yet_Another_Table` tables.
- Reconfigure all foreign key constraints back to ±`Blocking`.

In order to do that, I need to know:

- How to access all foreign key constraints in an SQL-Server database.
- How to turn these constraints' deletion rules into `Blocking` and `Cascade`.

As it is the intention to do this in a batchfile, I'd like to know the commandline commands for this.

Comment: Another option would be to delete first the children before the parent, in a stored procedure in example (and then, avoid to temporarily touch the tables structure)

Comment: @Cid: the problem is that there are different children, each having their own children, ..., and it becomes messy to make the corresponding SQL (currently, it looks like `DELETE FROM T1 WHERE Id IN (SELECT T1_Id FROM T2 WHERE T2_Id IN (SELECT T3.Id FROM T3 LEFT JOIN [T4] ON [T4].Id = T3.Id WHERE T3.entry = 'Some information'))`).

Comment: _it becomes messy_ sys.foreign_keys is your starting point - but your path may be impossible if the engine detects a chance of a cycle occurring for the cascade option. Far better to delete "bottom up" not "top down". You can lookup the syntax for altering constraints.

Comment: Do you mean there is no command to alter the constraint delete rule behaviour for all constraints?

Comment: [duplicate on dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/302390/sql-server-delete-rows-and-all-rows-in-according-tables-according-to-foreign-k)

Comment: And yes - there is no command line option.

Comment: @Dominique since it's just some maintenance script, it's okay to have a big script starting from bottom child to top parent with many nested select statements, you don't need optimization for a maintenance script, just the job to be done. That's annoying to write, but you'll have to do it only once